# determine whether a class's superclass implements a certain interface in java

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof

Let me know if I am wrong but in my experience the instanceof call does not do what I need it to.

I have an abstract class that implements an interface and explicitly overwrites all methods in the interface. I have a subclass of this class. How can I tell if the subclass is an instanceof the interface?

```
public interface IAnimal {
    public void eat();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Dog implements IAnimal {
    @Override
    public void eat(){
        //eat things
    }

    public abstract void bark();
}
```

---

```
public class Beagle extends Dog {
    @Override
    public void bark(){
        //specific bark
    }
}
```

---

So I have an instantiation of Beagle, how do i find out if it is an instance of IAnimal?

Comment: `instanceof` is what you are looking for.  why do you think it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: You have different experience than I do.

Comment: You can call object.getSuperclass().getInterfaces(), but instanceof ought to suffice

Answer (score 1):

You can do a

```
IAnimal.class.isAssignableFrom(Beagle.class)
```

or

```
IAnimal.class.isAssignableFrom(someObjectInstance.getClass());
```

or even instance of works with interfaces

```
if (object instanceof IAnimal) { }
```